# Masstransit does not fetch messages from azure servicesbus

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus, masstransit

Hi I have a publisher and consumer

The registration for the publisher seems very simple

```
 services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    
                    cfg.Host(configInstance.AzureServiceBusSettings.Connectionstring);
                    cfg.AutoStart = true;
                }
                );
            });
```

The registration for the consumer looks like this

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
    x.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
    x.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
    x.AddActivities(entryAssembly);
    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(configuration.AzureServiceBusSettings.Connectionstring);
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
                   
});
```

When I start this two projects it will create me the subscriptions and queues

For example the debug output from the consumer

```
[21:53:35 DBG] Create queue: hello
[21:53:40 DBG] Queue: hello (dead letter)
[21:53:44 DBG] Endpoint Ready: sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/hello
[21:53:44 INF] Bus started: sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/
```

This reflects the state of the servicebus, there is one queue called hello and a subscription

So my consumer looks like this

```
public class HelloConsumer : IConsumer<Hello>
    {
        ILogger<HelloConsumer> _logger;
        public HelloConsumer(ILogger<HelloConsumer> logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Hello> context)
        {
            this._logger.LogInformation("HEllo");
            return Task.CompletedTask; 
        }
    }
```

Now when I send the "Hello" it will send to the queue
[image]

as you see I have 7 messages in it. But unfortunalley the messaged won't be fetched from the ASB. In the consumer log is no action in it.

I tried to delete the topics and queues, this throws me several 404 errors. So I think that it will be 2monitored" but why not fetchted?

Do I miss here s.th.?

I am using the following nuget version

```
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core" Version="8.0.16" />
```

Aditional information: The Servicebus has a standard plan selected.

Comment: refer  [Masstransit](https://masstransit.io/quick-starts/azure-service-bus)

Comment: will give a sample example how  to connect with azure service bus with Masstransit

Comment: I did this already, as you see in my code there are the same lines for registration

Comment: I tried this way ```  x.UsingAzureServiceBus(configure: (context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.Host(connectionString: "connectionstring");
                            cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint("sampath", "sampath", e =>
                            {
                                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                            });
                            

                        });
                        
                    });
                    services.AddHostedService<worker>(); ```

Comment: In [console](https://i.imgur.com/grxvBq5.png)                                                    [Output](https://i.imgur.com/5IKLwlW.png) incoming and outgoing [message](https://i.imgur.com/vAH3HS0.png)

Comment: OK I will try, so for my understanding is that I will ad a separate "listener" to the queue. So in fact is that masstransit creates the queues and topics also. The forwarding rulez. Hope that I can get more insights. It seems for me the s.th. Blockers the receiving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. So it was reproducable when I remove the existing nuget package to masstransit.Rabbitmq. After that the messages are fetched all again.
So I don't know if this is the real problem but that's at my environment a solution.

So in fact it was maybe overlapping the logic I think

Answer (score 0):

> using this reference [Azure Service Bus MassTransit](https://masstransit.io/quick-starts/azure-service-bus) able to fetch messages Thank @Chris Patterson

```cs
x.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
                       x.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
                       x.AddActivities(entryAssembly);
                       x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                           {
                               cfg.Host(connectionString: "Endpoint=sb://samp12334.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=z ");
                               cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                           });
                   
                   });
                   services.AddHostedService<worker>();
               });
   }
}
```

```cs
 public class HelloConsumer :
        IConsumer<Hello>
    {
        readonly ILogger<HelloConsumer> _logger;
        public HelloConsumer(ILogger<HelloConsumer> logger) 
         { 
          _logger = logger;
        }
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Hello> context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(message: "Hello{Name}", context.Message.Name);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**For queue:**

```cs
x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => { cfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://your-service-bus-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=your-access-key"); 
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("your-queue-name", e => { e.ConfigureConsumer<MyMessageConsumer>(context); }); });
```

- For more details refer @[Chris Patterson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8marp1oyY_I)

Comment: That's weird, the same solution as in the YouTube video doesn't receive any kind of message. No consumer will be executed. I had selected the standard plan for Azure service bus. Maybe I use the wrong assem ly?

Comment: Great to hear that you figure out the issue with nuget package of ```masstransit.Rabbitmq```

Comment: Jep it was only luck, but helpful to document it. I will try to figure out why. Maybe it can be a contributed pr for the project 